# What the purpose of the `pass` statement?

Tags: python

Seems like `pass` is just a reserved word that isn't really needed. Python could use the convention of having a single line `None` statement to accomplish the same thing.

For example, I see very little difference between

```
while doing_a_thing():
   pass
```

and

```
while doing_a_thing():
   None
```

I suppose having `pass` is slightly more readable, but to my mind, it is a poor trade off against removing such a common word from the choices of functions/variables.

Just wondering if anyone knows more history and/or Python usage that I'm not aware of.

Comment: It can probably be argued that putting the value `None` on a single line is more confusing than introducing a new statement (`pass`).

Comment: Yes, it would be one more convention to learn. But in Python I think the trend (rightly) is on giving more freedom to the programmer in exchange for learning and following a reasonable set of conventions.

Comment: Well, since we do not have brackets to denote empty body of something, some kind of no-op statement had to be included. On why "pass" and not some other word, I guess it's _primarily opinion-based_.

Comment: My point is that a `None`, by itself, is a no-op statement. So really there isn't a need to introduce another reserved word.

Comment: There can be a need to introduce a new keyword if it makes the language easier to understand / learn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`None` already has meaning in Python. It is not a statement, but [a value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html). It can be used to flag a variable that does not yet have a standard value, or as the "return value" of a function that does not return anything.

So using it as a statement would be more confusing than using the new keyword `pass`.

Comment: It's not really a new use, just an expression that doesn't save its value. You could use `0` or `math.pi` or `2+2` or `"pass"` for the same purpose.

Comment: @kindall: You are right, of course, but I didn't have time to add details. ZWiki has added some, so I don't need to. My point is that using a value to *act as a null statement* would be confusing. I know it can do that, but in Python, ["Explicit is better than implicit"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to piggy-back off Rory a bit here.

`None` is a value, whereas `pass` is a statement.

For instance if you want a default value for a function you would do

```
def my_func(val1, val2=None):
    # Some stuff here
```

Where `None` is used to denote that the default value of `val2` is None.

If you have a class, however, you may see `pass` in this way:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Where `pass` may be there because you want to define the `__init__` method later, or to denote that it does nothing for the class.

Either way, `pass` is to say, "I could do something here, but I prefer not to". And `None` is an actual value that you are explicitly meaning to say "Yes, I am giving this value `None`

EDIT:
I understand more of the confusion now.

Because you see that:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

could be written as

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        None
```

This is not Pythons way of saying that `None` is equivalent to `pass` here. It is simply saying that providing only a `value` as a no-op, will have the same effect. So that means I could also do:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        12
```

And this of course doesn't make sense, why would you ever put `12` there? The point here is that the effects are the same, but the meanings are different in this case. And in a lot of cases `None` and `pass` are not interchangeable such as default arguments

Comment: Good catch. I meant statement, but always think of it as a placeholder for myself

Comment: my point is that in your example, you could replace `pass` with `None` and the code would behave exactly the same way.

Comment: @PeteCacioppi, yes, but I could replace `pass` with `None` or any other value such as `12`. It is not that `None` is equivalent to `pass` here, but that you can put any `value` under `init` and it will do nothing.

Comment: In this case I think `return` is actually clearer. The only place I would say `pass` is clearer is in a do-nothing `except` block.

Comment: @kindall I suppose I just prefer `pass` because I'm used to it from `minimal classes` with Python, and I've carried it over to blank __init__

Comment: sure, you could use `12` instead of `pass`, but that would be a bad convention. Wheras, a world where Python doesn't have `pass` but instead recognizes the convention of using `None` to the same effect would be a better world, since it would have one fewer reserved word.

Comment: Python actually has very few reserved words compared to a lot of languages. (About 3/5 of Java and about 1/3 of C++) `pass` has been in the language a long time so I doubt it's going anywhere.